# How to insert into tempoary table twice

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've picked up some SQL similar to the following:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM tempdb..sysobjects WHERE name Like N'#tmp%'
 and id=object_id('tempdb..#tmp'))
DROP TABLE #tmp

into #tmp
select * from permTable
```

I need to add more data to #tmp before continuing processing:

```
insert into #tmp
select * from permTable2
```

But this gives errors because SQL has assumed sizes and types for #tmp columns (e.g. if permTable has a column full of ints but permTable2 has column with same name but with a NULL in one record you get "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IsPremium', table 'tempdb.dbo.#tmp").

How do I get #tmp to have the types I want? Is this really bad practise?

Comment: are you saying permTable and permTable2 have different schemas?

Comment: They don't exist as this is a simplified example but for the purposes of this example the tables will have the same schemas

Comment: BTW - I would avoid select * into - this will make any change to the source table a breaking change.

Comment: Can you do a `UNION ALL` between your two selects to insert them at one time?  This would create your temp table with the right column setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered creating a table var instead?  You can declare the columns like such

```
declare @sometable table(
     SomeField [nvarchar](15),
     SomeOtherField [decimal](15,2));
```

Comment: Cool, looks good. Is sometable created in the same place, have the same life cycle etc as #tmp?

Comment: Table vars go out of scope with the proc or function, where temp tables go out of scope at the end of the session.  See http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-temp-table-or-a-table-variable.html for some more details

Answer (score 1):

This is why select into is a poor idea for your problem. Create the table structure specifically with a create table command and then write two insert statements.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible.

If you need to generate the table definition typelist now, 
create a view from the select statement, and read the columns and their definition from information_schema... (this work of art won't consider decimal and/or datetime2)

Note: this will give you the lowest possible field-length for varchar/varbinary columns you currently selected. 
You need to adjust them manually...

```
SELECT 
      ','
    + COLUMN_NAME 
    + ' ' 
    + DATA_TYPE
    + ' '
    + ISNULL
    (
          '(' 
          + 
          CASE 
            WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1 
                THEN 'MAX' 
            ELSE CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS varchar(36)) 
            END 
        + ')' 
        , '' 
    ) 
    + ' '
    + CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN 'NOT NULL' ELSE '' END 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = '________theF'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

And the field-list for the insert-statement:

```
SELECT 
      ',' + COLUMN_NAME 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = '________theF'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```